# unable to create alias in apache

Tags: apache2, xampp

I'm new to Apache. Following a tutorial, I am trying to set an alias in Apache to look and serve files from a folder (project). Other than htdocs, this was my code to create alias:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /project/ "C:/project/"
    Alias /project "C:/project"
</IfModule>
<Directory "C:/project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This doesn't work and when I type localhost/project/ in browser, the browser throws access forbidden.

How do I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change your security settings on C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
The directory diretive must be on this file or it will always show the forbidden error.

Comment: can yu explain a bit deeper?? will be appreciated

Comment: Sure, in the file  C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf everything but c:\xampp\htdocs is forbidden. I thought you've alrealdy put in your directory directive to allow c:\project but now I see you didn't. Stop apache and add this to the httpd.conf file:   <Directory C:\project>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 Deny from none
 </Directory>
Then you can start apache again. Hope it really helps.